# rsync to remote without destination directory

Tags: linux, rsync

I have run an rsync command to send local files to a remote server, but I forgot to specify the destination directory. Where in the remote server have the files been copied? I ran the following command:

```
rsync -avz source_directory/ remote_user@192.168.1.100
```

The output says the files were transmitted, and if I run the same command again, it doesn't transmit the files, becouse there is no change. But I cant find the files in the remote server.

Comment: Perhaps it has created a directory called `remote_user@192.168.1.100` *on the local machine*, in whatever was the working directory when you ran the command.

Comment: This is my very first post. How can I set this question as "Resolved"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless `rsync` sees a colon (`:`) in the destination (or source) parameter it uses it as a local path. [`man rsync`](https://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) gives a *hint*:

```
 SYNOPSIS
        Local:  rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [DEST]

        Access via remote shell:
          Pull: rsync [OPTION...] [USER@]HOST:SRC... [DEST]
          Push: rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [USER@]HOST:DEST

        [...]
```

And later:

> The remote-shell transport is used whenever the source  or  destination  path contains a single colon (:) separator after a host specification.

I.e. no colon in either `SRC` or `DEST` and you're using the ‘Local’ variant.

([`scp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) has this habit too, as noted in numerous frustrated rants by its users.)